# Custom animations happen instantly after using swipe to delete

Tags: swift

In my `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function, I have code that will perform an animation once completed. However, the animations always happen instantly. I have tested the animations in other views, and they work perfectly fine. It seems this function disables animations. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Add the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: This happens with any animation in the function.